# Cognos Conditional Drill through

Tags: cognos-10

I have list report which has country like USA,UK,INDIA,SINGAPORE. but USA, UK only need to enable drill through with 2 different reports. Could any one send me the detailed steps ?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a variable called DrillThroughEnabled.
- Make the expression [Country] in ('USA', 'UK')
- Unlock the report
- Drag a conditional block into the country list cell
- Set the Block Variable property to your new variable
- Drag the existing data item into both Current Block values
- Add a drill through to the USA, UK valued one